# VirtueMart How to Add/Edit Extended Layout Menu items

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 1.5.24 and installed **VirtueMart 1.1.9 stable**.
I have added a new menu item in the vendor section on simple layout by editing `header.php`, but the item not displaying on extended layout.

How can I add the new item in extended layout also. Where do I need to edit?
Thanks in advance..